# POST with file_get_contents in PHP with Captcha

Tags: php, file-get-contents, captcha

I want to read an external site after submit code with captcha. But using (PHP) file_get_contents the captcha is loaded 2 times, so its wrong.

The Form load an image to solve the captcha and sent via POST to the original site that show the result. Normally I solve the captcha and than, in the new site, I read (with my eyes) the content.

Now I want to let PHP read the content. I always solve first the captcha (in my page) and than send it to the other site and let (php) "file_get_contents" read the content.

HERE MY CODE..

```
<?php
    $captcha = $_POST["captcha"];
?>
<html>

<form method="post" action="(this page)">
<img src="remote-captcha"><input type="text" name="captcha">
<submit>

<?php
    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
        'captcha' => $captcha
        )
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = file_get_contents('https://www.form-page', false, $context);
    $search = '/<div class="myclass">(.*)<\/div>/';
    preg_match($search, $result, $show);

echo $show[0];
?>
```

At this point the form is loaded 2 times so the captcha is wrong.

Can someone help me?

Comment: If that external site wanted you to be able to get their data this way, they would probably not have protected it with a CAPTCHA in the first place …

Comment: _“I always solve first the captcha (in my page) and than send it to the other site”_ - that’s not going to work … “your” CAPTCHA and “their” CAPTCHA are two completely different things, you can not take the solution/answer from yours, and expect that to work with theirs.

Comment: Is a classic public site but in their form they use a simple captcha. The only problem is send form 2 times with that code (so the captcha change again).

Comment: The form in my page works! The new page opened (on the external site) has the captcha solved and show the solution.

Comment: _“Is a classic public site“_ - that is barely relevant, _“but in their form they use a simple captcha”_ - that usually is what people do, when they don’t want any bots or automated scripts to access the content/data …

Comment: _“The form in my page works! The new page opened (on the external site) has the captcha solved and show the solution.”_ - that might work in your browser, because there any cookies for that other site are also available. But when you request that page using your PHP script, there aren’t any cookies, so that other site will consider you a “fresh” visitor, and create a new CAPTCHA …

Comment: Try this please... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMgaNK and in the other site you can read "CODICE FISCALE VALIDO" (valid code) if captcha is solved correctly.

Comment: Yes, that works, and No, it doesn’t prove anything - because that is a completely different scenario, than what you are trying to accomplish here. Go open https://telematici.agenziaentrate.gov.it/ in a second tab while you have that codepen open, delete the cookies for that domain in your browser dev tools, return to your codepen, and submit it …

Comment: The CAPTCHA is connected to the user session, so you would have to emulate that from within your PHP script - get a session cookie, request the CAPTCHA image _via PHP_ (if you let your browser do it directly, it will be a different session), and send the session cookie back with the next request.

Comment: I've a form that need only one field must be "valid" before submit and only that site can validate, so i need to read that site to automatic stop submit if the value is not valid.
I'm studing CURL method. But i don't find an example with captcha.